# Accessing Object attributes

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function User(name,age){
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
      }
      var user = new User('Daniel', 45 );
      document.write(user[name]+' '+'is'+' '); //line 1
      document.write(user[age]+' '+'years old!'); // line 2
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

In above code,
              When i tried accessing properties of object user
              For name, i got 'undefined' as output
              For age, i got Error saying that age is Not defined
         Not able to understand why I'm getting Error for line 2 
         and 'undefined' value for line 1. Both should give same Error Right?
    Please clarify my doubt here.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are accessing them wrong. `user[name]` is not the right syntax to access object property.

Should be:

```
user['name']
```

or even simpler:

```
user.name
```

Further reading about accessing properties on objects:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Answer (score 0):

You should specify as name and age as string . it should be like this `user['name']`

```html
<html>
            <head>
                <script>
                    function User(name,age){
                        this.name=name;
                        this.age=age;
                    }
                    var user = new User('Daniel', 45 );
                    document.write(user["name"]+' '+'is'+' '); //line 1
                    document.write(user["age"]+' '+'years old!'); // line 2
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>

            </body>
        </html>
```

OR just use . notation

```html
<html>
            <head>
                <script>
                    function User(name,age){
                        this.name=name;
                        this.age=age;
                    }
                    var user = new User('Daniel', 45 );
                    document.write(user.name+' '+'is'+' '); //line 1
                    document.write(user.age+' '+'years old!'); // line 2
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>

            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a property of the window object named `name`.
What it is or for I have no idea. 
[EDIT] [the name of the window is used primarily for setting targets for hyperlinks and forms.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) 
So since it it defined you don't get the Not defined error as you get in line 2.
`user[name]` is equivalent to `user[window.name]`, which is `user['']`, since the window name wasn't set.

Comment: Thank you for the answer